# Use files from /usr/local/share inside OS X app bundle

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I’m writing Qt application using some 3rd party library. I want to package it into a bundle.

I’m using [macdeployqt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool) and this tool isn’t just copying Qt Frameworks, but also 3rd party library into `Contents/Frameworks` inside the app bundle.

The problem is that this 3rd party library need some additional file to work properly. Originally library is installed in `/usr/local/lib` and some necessary stuff is located at `/usr/local/share`.

How to package this stuff into app bundle?

Comment: I think it depends on how the specific library is coded. If the paths are hard coded as full paths or relative to some system path, then there's really nothing you can do. One possible solution is to include the files as resources and install them during the startup of your app when you detect that they are missing in the user's system.

Comment: @Stephen Chu: you are right. I found a place in the library source code where /usr/local/share/... is hard coded. I will stick to the solution you offered. Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how the specific library is coded. If the paths are hard coded as full paths or relative to some system path, then there's really nothing you can do. One possible solution is to include the files as resources and install them during the startup of your app when you detect that they are missing in the user's system.